# Move Date Heading from Top to Bottom

Tags: php, html

I have date headings for each group of the same date. These date headings currently appear at the top of each group of the same date. I want the date headings instead to be at the bottom of each group of the same date. I've tried to do it but having no luck.  Can anyone show me how to change this?  Thanks

See what I mean [in this link](http://althedge.xyz/index2.html).

```
<?php

// Database Settings 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', '*****');
define('DB_USER', '*****');
define('DB_PASS', '*****');
define('DB_NAME', '*****');

// Connection to Database
$database = new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

$sql = 'SELECT * '
        . ' FROM crypto ORDER BY Date DESC';

$resultSet = $database->query($sql);


$currentDate = false;
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())

{
if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate){
 echo
  '<strong>' .  
 $row['Date'] .  
  '</strong>' ;
$currentDate = $row['Date'];  
}
 echo 

 '<ul><li>' . 
 '<A HREF="'.  
 $row["Link"].
 '">'. 
 $row["Article"].
 $row["Date"].
 '</A>'.
 '</li></ul>';

 }  

$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you linked to is outputting different code than the code you show above. There are no `<li>` tags on your site itself, for example.

Still, you should just be able to move the `if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate){}` block to below your secondary echo to display the date at the bottom, as such:

```
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo '<ul><li><A HREF="' . $row["Link"] . '">' . $row["Article"] . $row["Date"] . '</A></li></ul>';

  if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate){
    echo '<strong>' . $row['Date'] . '</strong>';
    $currentDate = $row['Date'];  
  }

}
```

Note that I've also formatted this to make it more legible.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than echo the date heading you can save it to a variable like follows

```
....
$lastHeading = '';
$currentDate = false;
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
  if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate){
    echo $lastHeading;
    $lastHeading =  '<strong>' .  $row['Date'] .  '</strong>' ;
    $currentDate = $row['Date'];  
  }
....
}
echo $lastHeading;
```

Comment: Hey, it worked great for the first 2 dates but left off the last date at the bottom?  Thanks

Comment: `echo $lastHeading` after the end of the while loop